# "Curved" Powerline/Airline status on Vim

Tags: vim, fonts, arch-linux, vim-plugins

I have installed [vim-airline](https://github.com/vim-airline/vim-airline) plugin for Vim, and I should have had a "curved" "powerline" status line.

[image]

But mine is:

[image]

The font I use is `DejaVu Sans Mono for Powerline` from `ttf-dejavu-sans-mono-powerline` package.

I tried to install and use `PowerlineSymbols` font of `powerline-fonts` package but it conflicts with the former, and the terminal doesn't start up even if it is successfully installed by deleting the former.

What should I do to get the status line above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set:

```
    let g:airline_powerline_fonts = 1
    let g:Powerline_symbols = 'fancy'
```

Maybe you want as well use different symbols instead the triangles.

```
    let g:airline_left_sep = '»'
    let g:airline_left_sep = ''
    let g:airline_right_sep = '«'
    let g:airline_right_sep = ''
```

Comment: Thanks! `airline_powerline_fonts` was enough to display everything correctly. I think the second one (`Powerline_symbols`) is set (to `fancy`) by default, as it doesn't seem to alter anything in my config.